# What are the circumstances that lead to Kondou being the sole Shinsengumi leader?

Tags: japan

After the assassination of [Serizawa Kamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serizawa_Kamo), this left [Kondou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kond%C5%8D_Isami) and [Tonouchi](https://wiki.samurai-archives.com/index.php?title=Tonouchi_Yoshio) as the remaining faction leaders. From what I understand, Tonouchi knew or even helped Kondou get rid of Serizawa but, then, Kondou killed Tonouchi at Yojou bridge to become the sole Shinsengumi leader. Was this an assassination or was it some sort of duel that was agreed upon?

Either way, what did Tonouchi expect would happen after Serizawa's faction was wiped out?

Was [Matsudaira Katamori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsudaira_Katamori) involved, at all, in this? Did he expect Kondou to kill Tonouchi?

Comment: All these names being thrown around ... I wonder if OP was seriously doing any research. OP is asking about Mibu _ronins_ and Matsudaira clan (of which Tokugawa shogunate came from). This question almost seems trivial without the context.